# Facebook notifications.sendEmail - Insufficient permissions

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbconnect

Hello when I try to send an E-Mail over Facebook with notifications.sendEmail i get the error    Insufficient permissions - Code 200. Both Users the Sender and the (not working) Receiver have installed my Facebook Application with extended permissions

- email
- publish_stream

really both sender and receiver. normally it is not necessary that the receiver needs that settings too (in first instance). because the receiver should get a message asking for install the Application to receive the mail, am I right?

Do you know what permission I forgot? Maybe a setting in the Application itself?

=> notifications.send works normally

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It kind of sounds like the computer running the API call needs to be added to a server whitelist.  Have you checked your application settings for server whitelist/blacklist stuff?